# Difference of variability and its significance

Tags: statistical-significance, variability

I am quite new to statistics and I am trying to interpret a result I found in a medical study. Specifically, I want to know what methods they used so I can reproduce those in an analysis of a study of my own. Unfortunately, the methods section is missing...

Here is the sentence:

> The variability of the measurement was 7.39%, significantly smaller than reference inter-observer variability of 8.2% (p=0.002).

I think the inter-observer variability here referes to a 95% confidence radius. However, I am unsure what method was used to show it is "significantly smaller" and for the calculation of the p-value in the brackets.

Comment: They're actually talking about some measure of reliability, which is a way of assessing the quality of a measurement instrument. "Variability" as they mention it is 1- reliability. You can compute reliability for each instrument and presumable to test whether the reliability of two instruments differs. The authors have chosen to report this as "variability", but the p-value refers to the difference in reliability between the two instruments.

Comment: @Noah what would be the specific test I need to apply to reproduce this? Thank you!